# Control Flow of php

Tags: php

I have a php script example1.php

How would the control flow be when I call another php script example2.php from example1.php.

E.g
example1.php looks like this

```
....
...
....
shell_exec("php -q example2.php") (calling example2.php from example1.php)
.....
.....
```

How does the control flow work for this ? Does example1.php wait until example2.php completes execution and then continious with rest of code logic or does it just continues allowing example2.php to run independently ?

Thanks !

Comment: A file inclusion is basically nothing else than a function call with shared scope. (Just like `eval()`)

Comment: Please post some actual code, what you've written isn't clear. Are you using `include`, or are you calling a function? You can't just put the name of a PHP script in another PHP script like you've shown.

Comment: Could you elaborate on control flow, will example1 wait for example2.php to complete before continuing with further logic

Comment: @Barmar, I am not using include, that is not a function but actual php file which I execute through shell_exec(example2.php)

Comment: @user2856109 depends on the exact command if it'll wait.

Answer (score 1):

`shell_exec()` executes the shell command and waits for it to finish. The fact that the command you're running is `php` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

if you have test1.php:

```
echo "test1";
include("test2.php");
echo "test3";
```

and test2.php

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10000; $i++) {

}
echo "test2";
```

Your result will be:
test1
test2
test3

However, the code after include will be execute after include process finish.